# Querying Couchbase Bucket from Postman - Unrecognized parameter in request

Tags: postman, couchbase

Using the Postman tool, I'm trying to query a Couchbase bucket. I'm getting an error response 1065 that there is an "unrecognized parameter in request". The query will work fine within the Couchbase workbench, but I need to be able to do this from Postman.

I'm making a POST request with this body:

```
{
    "statement" : "SELECT * from `myBucketName` where id = "aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee""
}
```

There error message is:

```
"msg": "Unrecognized parameter in request: {\n\"statement\" : \"SELECT  from `myBuckeyName` where _id "
```

I think this is just an issue with how my request body is formatted, I'm just new to this and not sure how it should be formatted based off the error I'm getting.

Comment: I'm curious why you need to use Postman instead of the Couchbase workbench. Especially for writing N1QL, the workbench will be a much better tool.

Comment: @MatthewGroves It's a good question, and I much rather use the Couchbase workbench. However, I do not have access to the workbench in the environment that I'm working in.

Comment: Hmm, why not...?

Comment: @MatthewGroves My workbench access is restricted in this particular environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

1. Open Postman
2. Select POST
3. Use a URL of http://localhost:8093/query/service
4. Under "Authorization", use Basic Auth (with the username/password you've created for Couchbase)
5. Under "Body", select "x-www-form-urlencoded"
6. Add a KEY of statement and a value of your query
7. Click SEND

I got a 200 OK response with the results of the query. Screenshot:

[image: Postman with Couchbase REST API screenshot]

You should definitely check out the [Couchbase REST API documentation](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-rest-api/exsuccessful.html). It uses curl instead of Postman, but that's a translation you'll eventually get used to.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your reply. Using x-www-form-urlencoded and adding the relevant key/value worked. I had been using raw for the body. Still not sure what is wrong with how I had my raw body formatted because I think I should be able to get it to work that way. But regardless, your suggestion does work. Thanks a ton!